# PAGE_CACHE_FILTER_STATE HTTP Header

Tags: java, caching, http-headers

I can't find information anywhere regarding this HTTP Header: `PAGE_CACHE_FILTER_STATE`.

When I try to access my RSS feed from a browser, this header has the value of `NoCacheRequest`, but when I access it from my Java application (`URL.openConnection()`), I've noticed that it gets set to `FromCacheRequest` and my RSS doesn't appear to update.

So I have two questions:

1. What is this HTTP header?
2. How can I make `PAGE_CACHE_FILTER_STATE: NoCacheRequest` for all requests?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard about nor seen `PAGE_CACHE_FILTER_STATE` before either, so I can't help you out with the actual specifications for it. It *looks* like a custom header telling you whether a cached version of the content was used or not.

To avoid caching, you could try programmatically adding something different to the URL each time. For example, you might add a random number:

`http://www.example.com/feed.rss?no_cache=564482`

`http://www.example.com/feed.rss?no_cache=984637`

You should also try sending the `Pragma: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: no-cache` HTTP headers when you request the RSS feed.